# Other programs support .blend

Tags: blend-files

Is there any program that import blender objects and animate them with it

Cuz i have made a 3d logo with blender and it is kind of difficult to animate it  (with my little experience ) with blender so is there any chance of another program??

Comment: there could be others, but why not exporting your modeled object to (say, .obj, or .fbx) and import it in your favourite animation package?

Comment: How do i do that ??

Comment: model your object in blender, then from the menu file > export, choose a format that is suitable for your other animation program. in the default install there are most popular ones, but you can enable others, from the user preference panel, "add-ons tab" (see menu file > user preferences...). knowing which program you wish to import it into, a few suggestion could be made...

Answer (score -1):

You can use After Effect with Element 3D and then export the blender file as an OBJ